# How to fetch all features, not just within the visible extent, using MapBox Studio hosted data?

Tags: query, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-studio

I uploaded a GeoJSON Dataset to MapBox Studio, then converted it into a Tileset. I'm displaying this in a MapBox GL-JS map:

```
map.addSource('regionsSource', {
  type: 'vector',
  url: 'mapbox://username.layerId'
});
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'regions',
  'source': 'regionsSource',
  'source-layer': layerName,
  ...
})
```

I need a way to fetch features from the regions layer via an attribute query, *whether or not they're in the current view extent*.

Unfortunately it seems that [querySourceFeatures](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#querysourcefeatures) "does not check tiles outside the currently visible viewport." [queryRenderedFeatures](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#queryrenderedfeatures) has a similar limitation.

How can I query features from a Tileset stored in MapBox studio, regardless of the current view extent?

Comment: There is no way with querySourceFeatures or queryRenderedFeatures.
The best way is to host the data in a database and get the desired values.
If you really want to do that with Mapbox studio, there is a custom solution to build.
1. select the extent.
2. use slippy tiles algorithm to query pbf tiles from Mapbox studio link to that extent. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames
3. convert pbf to geojson. https://github.com/mapbox/vt2geojson
Your results are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a custom solution to build.

1. Select the extent desired extent/bbox.
2. Use slippy tiles algorithm to query pbf tiles from Mapbox studio link to that extent/bbox.
   https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames
3. Convert pbf to geojson. [github.com/mapbox/vt2geojson](https://github.com/mapbox/vt2geojson)